# Batch script to check the java home

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, java-home

I need to check that whether java home is available in my system and if java home is not availkable it needs to display an error message and want to check the java version is less than 1.7.If it is greater than 1.7 it needs to display an error.is it possible.Currently i'm using the below script .Can any one suggest What are the changes need to mADe on the script.Or whether any new script needed.
Thanks in advance

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

:: possible locations under HKLM\SOFTWARE of JavaSoft registry data
set "javaNativeVersion="
set "java32ON64=Wow6432Node\"

:: for variables
::    %%k = HKLM\SOFTWARE subkeys where to search for JavaSoft key
::    %%j = full path of "Java Runtime Environment" key under %%k
::    %%v = current java version
::    %%e = path to java

set "javaDir="
set "javaVersion="
for %%k in ( "%javaNativeVersion%" "%java32ON64%") do if not defined javaDir (
    for %%j in (
        "HKLM\SOFTWARE\%%~kJavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"
    ) do for /f "tokens=3" %%v in (
        'reg query "%%~j" /v "CurrentVersion" 2^>nul ^| find /i "CurrentVersion"'
    ) do for /f "tokens=2,*" %%d in (
        'reg query "%%~j\%%v" /v "JavaHome"   2^>nul ^| find /i "JavaHome"'
    ) do ( set "javaDir=%%~e" & set "javaVersion=%%v" )
)

if not defined javaDir (
    echo Java not found
) else (
    echo JAVA_HOME="%javaDir%"
    echo JAVA_VERSION="%javaVersion%"
)

endlocal
pause
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Hi ,i need a batch script with above prerequisites.My above script is only displaying the java home and java version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LSS`, `GRT` and `EQU` and so on to compare string in batch.

- `EQU` = Equal to
- `NEQ` = Not equal to
- `LSS` = Less than
- `LEQ` = Less than or equal to
- `GTR` = Greater than
- `GEQ` = Greater than or equal to

Since you have got the version info in `%javaVersion%`, what you want is just display the error message.

You can modify you code into:

```
if not defined javaDir (
    echo Java not found
) else (
    echo JAVA_HOME="%javaDir%"
    echo JAVA_VERSION="%javaVersion%"
    if "%javaVersion%" LSS "1.7" (
        echo Java version is too low!
        goto exit
    ) 
    if "%javaVersion%" GTR "1.7" (
        echo JAVA version is too high!
        goto exit
    )
)

:exit
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: Thanks Sid Zhang for the answer.But if java home is not set in the system it needs to show an error message .will it possible with this code segment.What are the changes that i need to make

Comment: Also it is showing the java home value in out put even the java home is not set in the system

Comment: @user3400717 The Java Home set in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment` may be different of what in environment varaibles. I suggest you use this way to set the `JAVA_HOME`. http://www.chriskopec.com/blog/2009/jun/15/automatic-discovery-java_home-batch-file/